# mapEither inserting both Left and Right

Tags: haskell, multiset

Using the function `mapEither` for multiset's I can turn a `MultiSet` into a pair of two multisets. When `f` is returning `Left` the element is inserted into the first `Multiset` of the pair, and if `f` is returning `Right` the element is inserted into the second `MultiSet` of the pair.

How can I insert the same element into both `MultiSet`s at the same time, as if `f` were returning `Right` and `Left` at the same time?

```hs
f:: LocalType -> Either LocalType LocalType
f (Sometype lt) = Left lt -- And Right lt
f lt = Left lt

parRule :: (MultiSet LocalType) -> (MultiSet LocalType)
parRule sequent = do 
    let list = MultiSet.mapEither f sequent
```

For reference, I use Data.Multiset package, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html.

Comment: simply tweak [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.3/docs/src/Data.MultiSet.html#mapEither) as dfeuer [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338412/mapeither-returning-both-left-and-right#comment124339080_70338724).

Comment: @WillNess, I don't really like how that's implemented.

Comment: @dfeuer yes I got that, so I linked to your comment -- I take it as suggesting building the two multisets as we go instead of adding the pairs to the two lists. I haven't read your answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the function `mapEither` from the `Data.MultiSet` and modified it such that it supports `These` type.

```hs
-- | /O(n)/. Map and separate the 'This' and 'That' or 'These' results 
-- modified function of mapEither to map both cases in case f return These
-- code of mapEither found in source code, 
mapThese :: (Ord b, Ord c) => (a -> These b c) -> MultiSet a -> (MultiSet b, MultiSet c)
mapThese f = (\(ls,rs) -> (MultiSet.fromOccurList ls, MultiSet.fromOccurList rs)) . mapThese' . MultiSet.toOccurList
  where mapThese' [] = ([],[])
        mapThese' ((x,n):xs) = case f x of
           This  l -> let (ls,rs) = mapThese' xs in ((l,n):ls, rs)
           That r -> let (ls,rs) = mapThese' xs in (ls, (r,n):rs)
           These u i -> let (ls,rs) = mapThese' xs in ((u,n):ls, (i,n):rs)
```

In the case f returns `These`, both MultiSet's have an added element.

Comment: Most of what `mapThese'` does is captured by [`partitionHereThere`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-1.1.1.1/docs/Data-These.html#v:partitionHereThere). So I might write `mapThese f m = bimap MS.fromOccurList MS.fromOccurList $ partitionHereThere [bimap (,n) (,n) (f x) | (x, n) <- MS.toOccurList m]` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a type like [`These`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these/docs/Data-These.html) to capture the ability to return both. You can then use [`toAscOccurList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset/docs/Data-MultiSet.html#v:toAscOccurList) and `fromOccurList` (or `fromAscOccurList` if your function is monotonic) to compute the new `MultiSet`.

Comment: That's the strategy the package uses, but it strikes me as rather surprising. Why not build the new multisets eagerly while dividing up the results? It smells of excessive laziness.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`These`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these/docs/Data-These.html) as Daniel Wagner suggests, but I would use a slightly different function to start with, which seems like a slightly better match to the library API. Furthermore, I would recommend a different implementation strategy for performance.

```
data SP a b = SP !a !b
toPair :: SP a b -> (a, b)
toPair (SP a b) = (a, b)

mapPairOcc :: (Ord b, Ord c) => (a -> Occur -> ((b, Occur), (c, Occur))) -> MultiSet a -> (MultiSet b, MultiSet c)
mapPairOcc f = toPair . mapPairOcc' f

mapPairOcc' :: (Ord b, Ord c) => (a -> Occur -> ((b, Occur), (c, Occur))) -> MultiSet a -> SP (MultiSet b) (MultiSet c)
mapPairOcc' f = foldl' go (SP empty empty) . toAscOccurList
  where
    go (SP bs cs) a
      | ((b, bn), (c, cn)) <- f a
      = SP (insertMany b bn bs) (insertMany c cn cs)
```

When you know that `f` is strictly monotone in the sense that

```
a < a' ==> fst (f a) < fst (f a') /\ snd (f a) < snd (f a')
```

it's possible to do better, building the results in O(n) time. The best way to do this seems to be to use `Data.Map` internals. I'll reuse the `SP` type from above.

```
import Data.Map.Lazy (Map)
import Data.MultiSet (MultiSet, Occur)
import qualified Data.MultiSet as MS
import qualified Data.Map.Internal as M
import Control.Monad (guard)

-- | Map over the keys and values in a map, producing
-- two maps with new keys and values. The passed function
-- must be strictly monotone in the keys in the sense
-- described above.
mapMaybeWithKey2Mono :: (k -> a -> (Maybe (l,b), Maybe (m,c))) -> Map k a -> (Map l b, Map m c)
mapMaybeWithKey2Mono f = toPair . mapMaybeWithKey2Mono' f

mapMaybeWithKey2Mono' :: (k -> a -> (Maybe (l,b), Maybe (m,c))) -> Map k a -> SP (Map l b) (Map m c)
mapMaybeWithKey2Mono' _ M.Tip = SP M.Tip M.Tip
mapMaybeWithKey2Mono' f (M.Bin _ kx x l r)
  | (fl, fr) <- f kx x
  = SP (groink fl mfl1 mfr1) (groink fr mfl2 mfr2)
  where
    groink :: Maybe (q, x) -> Map q x -> Map q x -> Map q x
    groink m n o = case m of
      Just (k', y) -> M.link k' y n o
      Nothing -> M.link2 n o
    SP mfl1 mfl2 = mapMaybeWithKey2Mono' f l
    SP mfr1 mfr2 = mapMaybeWithKey2Mono' f r
```

Using this new general `Map` function, we can define the function we want on multisets:

```
mapPairAscOcc :: (a -> Occur -> ((b, Occur), (c, Occur))) -> MultiSet a -> (MultiSet b, MultiSet c)
mapPairAscOcc f m
  | (p, q) <- mapMaybeWithKey2Mono go . MS.toMap $ m
  = (MS.fromOccurMap p, MS.fromOccurMap q)
  where
     -- a -> Occur -> (Maybe (b, Occur), Maybe (c, Occur))
    go a aocc
      | ((b, bocc), (c, cocc)) <- f a aocc
      = ( (b, bocc) <$ guard (bocc > 0)
        , (c, cocc) <$ guard (cocc > 0) )
```

Comment: A strict pair type is also available in the `strict` package as [`Data.Strict.Tuple.Pair`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.4.0.1/docs/Data-Strict-Tuple.html#t:Pair). Alternatively, in this case, `go` can use strict pattern matching on a (lazy) tuple instead of strict construction, e.g., with `BangPatterns`, replacing the pattern `SP bs cs` with `(!bs, !cs)`.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I've had better luck, on both the human side and compiler side, using strict pairs than using bang patterns everywhere. Admittedly, my experience comparing them was mostly in the context of polymorphic recursion, where GHC's optimizer tends to need a lot more hand-holding than in more typical circumstances. It's nice to know about the `strict` package, though in practice I've often needed much more specific (often partially) strict types than any library is likely to offer (things like `data HSPN a b = HSPN !Int !a b`).

Comment: I guess one could also wish for an O(n) solution for when `f` is monotonic.

Comment: @DanielWagner, my attempt to be very clever failed. I give you an implementation of the monotonic version that uses `Data.Map` internals for great justice.